# Error al desplegar en weblogic: El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada

Tags: windows, weblogic, windows-server-2012

al momento de empezar el despliegue y luego de escoger el archivo war que voy a desplegar, al darle siguiente me está saliendo este error:

> No se ha podido acceder a la aplicación seleccionada
>
> C:\wls12210\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\tmp.appmergegen_1543536501548_nuevaepsweb.war\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada): probably the string length of the path of the file being extracted was too long or failed to overwrite the file

El weblogic está montado sobre un servidor windows server 2012

Answer (score 0):

Como el tamaño de la ruta que escribes es [menor a los 256 caracteres](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation), lo más probable es que no tengas permisos de escritura y lo más conveniente sea [correrlo como administrador](https://community.oracle.com/message/14076817#14076817).

Si no te fuera posible estar como administrador, puedes definir una ruta a la que tengas permisos de escritura [mediante banderas](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1017876):

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dweblogic.j2ee.application.tmpDir=c:/temp %JAVA_OPTIONS%
```